# Loading a content from html file with jquery into a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I am trying to populate main content div from another html file.

I have first two links like this:

```
<a href="" class="load-page" data-location="./content/johdanto.html">Johdanto</a>
<a href="" class="load-page" data-location="./content/vastuualueet.html">Vastuualueet</a>
```

and main content div set up like so:

```
<div class="main" id="content">
```

jquery like this

```
$('.load-page').on('click', function(event)
{event.preventDefault();
$('#content').load($(this).data('location'));
});
```

populating the div works but it only loads the first file no matter what link I click, need some help with this :(

Comment: The JS logic works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/43Lacoy7/. Check the network tab to ensure that the response from the AJAX request has not been cached. Also check to ensure that the two pages don't have the same content :) Finally, ensure that the `./` routing works on your server. Normally it's `../` to go up a directory in a browser. You may be better off basing all paths from the root folder instead: ```/content/...```

Comment: Yea didn't even think that these get cached. Thanks a lot for a swift answer! Trying to learn for a school project and been scratching my head the whole day...

Comment: I'm not sure about what you can and can't do with a reputation of 1, but you might be able to remove your fix from the question and add it as an answer, i.e. answer your own question.

Comment: @wazz will fix that now, thanks! Takes a day before I can accept my own answer as solution thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if someone runs into this,

```
$('.load-page').on('click', function(event)
{event.preventDefault();
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$('#content').load($(this).data('location'));
});
```

setting the cache to false fixed it for me :)